# Redis - Tomcat Session Manager : Read from Slave

Tags: redis, tomcat7

I am using redis(Redis 3.1) as session store for tomcat(Tomcat 7). To ensure high availability, there is a sentinel setup and two instances(master and slave) of redis server. The slave is configured as read-only. After running few tests and verifying the statistics, it's observerd there are no read requests sent to the slave. All the read requests are processed by the master alone.

Could you please let me know how I can make the slave serve the read requests?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Redis based Tomcat Session Manager provided by [Redisson](https://redisson.org). It allows to manage which type of node use for read operation (master, slave or both master and slave). Perfectly works in Sentinel/Cluster modes.